# How can I create screen sharing mobile application using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a mobile application using flutter.
Is this possible if not then is there any native program or source then please provide that.

Comment: Yes you can create a mobile application using Flutter...however you can choose to write native applications with provided Sdk of the platorm

Comment: Please attach the code you tried so far.

Comment: try native sdk of android or ios.

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi could you please explain more how we can do that?